# How to read the cursor more than once

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am working on Oracle stored procedure and need inputs on the below use case.

1. Stored procedure will fetch the data in the cursor after some calculations.
2. The cursor data will be returned to front end.

Now I have a requirement to add cursor data in another table and send to front end.

As per my understanding, once we open and read cursor to store in another table, we can't send the same cursor to front end. We will have to fetch data from source table again and send to front end. 
This impacts the performance.

Any ideas on achieving this without fetching twice?

Comment: You question really isn' t clear. To start, fix the layout by using actual paragraphs. Secondly you will have to to a lot better with the problemm description itself.

Comment: @Kris: He wants to loop through the cursor data twice, but only execute the SQL statement once.

Comment: @pravin. If I understand your question correctly, could declare extra variable of the same type as the row cursor, then use that extra copy of data as needed? It is much easier to respond to questions that illustrates the input, the required output, the current code, current output, comments about why current output is not right and any error messages you might get. Good luck.

Comment: Why store the cursor results in another table? Use collection objects (of course, with their types defined in the schema). This will definitely improve your performance as it will reduce the context-switching that happens while writing data to tables. Also, please provide a working example so we can provide you with better solutions.